# Correct notation for index of subgroup [G:H]

Tags: math-mode, typography, relation-symbols

What is more "correct" from a typographical standpoint: `$[G:H]$` or `$[G \mathbin{:} H]`?
This notation appears in the index of subgroups/of submodules or in the degree of field extensions.

Comment: Dont forget `$[G\,{:}\,H]$` as a possibility.

Comment: FWIW, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_a_subgroup) just uses `[G:H]`

Comment: I've always used `[G:H]` because it's not really an operation. But I wouldn't disagree on consistent usage of `[G\mathbin:H]`